# How to handle subtract date query when production environment database is Oracle and for test environment is H2?

Tags: java, spring, testing, integration-testing, h2

How to handle subtract date query when production environment database is Oracle and for test environment is `H2` ?
For example our query in production is something like this :
Also configured as following :

```
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:file:~/testdb;MODE=Oracle;
    username: sa
    password:
  jpa:
    database: H2
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

For test environment it dose not work (in Intellij H2 console), so we change for test to :

From :

```
select SYSTIMESTAMP- 30 / 24 /60 from dual;
```

To:

```
select systimestamp - interval '30' minute from dual;
```

We use JDBCTemplate to run query in application test layer, Does it not working also in code ? This is only a pieces of queries, what is the best solution for handle it in test case writing?

Comment: _"production environment database is Oracle and for test environment is H2"_ -- That's not how testing works.  You cannot reliably test your code in an environment substantially different from production.  Whoever set this up doesn't understand software testing.

Comment: You _could_ tell h2 to behave like Oracle …

Comment: But this is why any O/R layer knows about SQL dialects.

Comment: I khow this is problem, and I asked for solution.@JimGarrison

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I updated  the question.